# How do I save data to a multi-dimensional Ruby hash then convert the hash to a single JSON file?

Tags: ruby, hash, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm working on a web scraper that scrapes the following data from a website.

- Group
- Category
- Search attributes

I'm using the following code to save the data into three separate (single dimensional) JSON file:

```
require 'mechanize'

@raw_groups_array = []
@raw_categories_array = []
@search_attributes = []

@groups_clean = []
@categories_clean = []

@categories_combined = []

@categories_hash = {}

# Initialize Mechanize object
a = Mechanize.new

# Begin magic
a.get('http://www.marktplaats.nl/') do |page|
  groups = page.search('//*[(@id = "navigation-categories")]//a')
  groups.each do |group|
    @raw_groups_array.push(group)
    @groups_clean.push(group.text)

    a.get(group[:href]) do |page_2|
      categories = page_2.search('//*[(@id = "category-browser")]//a')
      categories.each do |category|
        @raw_categories_array.push(category)
        @categories_clean.push(category.text)
        @categories_combined.push("#{group.text} | #{category.text}")

        a.get(category[:href]) do |page_3|
          search_attributes = page_3.search('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "heading", " " ))]')

          search_attributes.each do |attribute|
            @search_attributes.push("#{group.text} | #{category.text} | #{attribute.text}") unless attribute.text == 'Outlet '

            # Uncomment the line below if you want to see what's going on.
            # (it has minimal effect on performance)
            puts "#{group.text} | #{category.text} | #{attribute.text}" unless attribute.text == 'Outlet '
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# Write json files
File.open('json/prestige/prestige_groups.json', 'w') do |f|
  puts '# Writing groups'
  f.write(@groups_clean.to_json)
  puts '|-----------> Done.'
end

File.open('json/prestige/prestige_categories.json', 'w') do |f|
  puts '# Writing categories'
  f.write(@categories_clean.to_json)
  puts '|-----------> Done.'
end

File.open('json/prestige/prestige_combined.json', 'w') do |f|
  puts '# Writing combined'
  f.write(@categories_combined.to_json)
  puts '|-----------> Done.'
end

File.open('json/prestige/prestige_search_attributes.json', 'w') do |f|
  puts '# Writing search attributes'
  f.write(@search_attributes.to_json)
  puts '|-----------> Done.'
end

puts '# Finished.'
```

The code works. But I'm having a hard time refactoring it to create a ruby Hash in the following format:

```
{
  "category"=>{
    "name"=>"#{category}",
    "group"=>"#{group}",
    "search_attributes"=>{
      "1"=>"#{search_attributes[0]}",
      "2"=>"#{search_attributes[1]}",
      "."=>"#{search_attributes[.]}",
      "i"=>"#{search_attributes[i]}", # depending on search_attributes.length
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried things like:

```
...
search_attributes.each do |attribute|
  @categories_hash.store([:category][:name], category.text)
  @categories_hash.store([:category][:group], group.text)
  @categories_hash.store([:category][:search_attributes][:1], attribute.text)
end
...
```

But keep getting syntax errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Max suggested I try `Hash#[]` but this returns a Hash with a single category (the last one).

```
search_attributes.each_with_index do |attribute, index|
  @categories_hash[:category][:name] = category.text
  @categories_hash[:category][:group] = group.text
  @categories_hash[:category][:search_attributes][:"#{index}"] = attribute.text unless attribute.text == "Outlet "   
end
```

I've pasted the full code [here](https://gist.github.com/narzero/5b5c23ad3191167a37c4).

Comment: I don't think you understand how Hashes work. Each key in a Hash must be unique. `:category` is a Symbol, so you're overwriting the last value every time. Based on your original attempt, it doesn't look like you have a strong grasp of Ruby's syntax.

Comment: Hence the question I'm asking. I need help. This is what SO is for.

Comment: I understand that, but as it is it seems too broad. It is not clear to me where your misunderstanding lies, so I can't think of a single answer that would address it. Any decent Ruby tutorial should cover basics like these.

Comment: All I want is the following: I want one Ruby Hash containing all category data. I think I should not be using Symbols, since they have to be unique. I want to iterate over all the categories available and add them to the Hash.

Comment: Well I see that you have a variable `category`. How about using `category.text` instead of `:category`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24295433/2246700), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296579/2246700) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24297697/2246700) I have the fully working code:

```
require 'mechanize'

@hashes = []

# Initialize Mechanize object
a = Mechanize.new

# Begin scraping
a.get('http://www.marktplaats.nl/') do |page|
  groups = page.search('//*[(@id = "navigation-categories")]//a')
  groups.each_with_index do |group, index_1|

    a.get(group[:href]) do |page_2|
      categories = page_2.search('//*[(@id = "category-browser")]//a')
      categories.each_with_index do |category, index_2|

        a.get(category[:href]) do |page_3|
          search_attributes = page_3.search('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "heading", " " ))]')

          attributes_hash = {}

          search_attributes.each_with_index do |attribute, index_3|
            attributes_hash[index_3.to_s] = "#{attribute.text unless attribute.text == 'Outlet '}"
          end

          item = {
            id: "#{index_1}.#{index_2}",
            name: category.text,
            group: group.text,
            :search_attributes => attributes_hash
          }

          @hashes << item

          # Uncomment this if you want to see what's being pushed
          puts item
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# Open file and begin
File.open("json/light/#{Time.now.strftime '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'}_light_categories.json", 'w') do |f|
  puts '# Writing category data to JSON file'
  f.write(@hashes.to_json)
  puts "|-----------> Done. #{@hashes.length} written."
end

puts '# Finished.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you're using `Hash#store`? There is no easy way with that method.

Using `Hash#[]` is much nicer, I think.

```
@categories_hash[:category] ||= {}
@categories_hash[:category][:search_attributes] ||= {}
@categories_hash[:category][:search_attributes][:1] = attribute.text
```

The `||=` ensure that the subhash is initialized before you try to store something in it.

Comment: No particular reason. I was just trying a few things, but it wasn't working.

Is it possible to do an `Array#push` like method with `Hash#[]` or Ruby Hashes in general?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. In Ruby 1.9 and over, keys are always enumerated in the order they were added, so again `[]` is sufficient to add a key to the "end" of Hash.

Comment: I've updated the original question. Using Hash#[] doesn't append a new key value pair to the end of the Hash. After the code runs, `@ categories_hash` just contains the last one. Any ideas?