# Why does this JSON file get filled with 1747 times the last Hash data?

Tags: ruby, json, hash, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm using the following code to generate a JSON file containing all category information for a particular website.

```
require 'mechanize'

@hashes = []

@categories_hash = {}
@categories_hash['category'] ||= {}
@categories_hash['category']['id'] ||= {}
@categories_hash['category']['name'] ||= {}
@categories_hash['category']['group'] ||= {}

# Initialize Mechanize object
a = Mechanize.new

# Begin scraping
a.get('http://www.marktplaats.nl/') do |page|
  groups = page.search('//*[(@id = "navigation-categories")]//a')

  groups.each_with_index do |group, index_1|
    a.get(group[:href]) do |page_2|
      categories = page_2.search('//*[(@id = "category-browser")]//a')

      categories.each_with_index do |category, index_2|
        @categories_hash['category']['id'] = "#{index_1}_#{index_2}"
        @categories_hash['category']['name'] = category.text
        @categories_hash['category']['group'] = group.text

        @hashes << @categories_hash['category']

        # Uncomment if you want to see what's being written
        puts @categories_hash['category'].to_json
      end
    end
  end
end

File.open("json/magic/#{Time.now.strftime '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'}_magic_categories.json", 'w') do |f|
  puts '# Writing category data to JSON file'
  f.write(@hashes.to_json)
  puts "|-----------> Done. #{@hashes.length} written."
end

puts '# Finished.'
```

But this code returns a JSON file filled with just the last category data. For the full JSON file take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/narzero/84179b9368a7a3da987a). This is a sample:

```
[
   {
      "id":"36_17",
      "name":"Overige Diversen",
      "group":"Diversen"
   },
   {
      "id":"36_17",
      "name":"Overige Diversen",
      "group":"Diversen"
   },
   {
      "id":"36_17",
      "name":"Overige Diversen",
      "group":"Diversen"
   }, {...}
]
```

The question is, what's causing this and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *same* object, the result of `@categories_hash['category']`, is being updated each loop.

Thus the array is filled with the *same* object 1747 times, and the object reflects the mutations done on the last loop when it is viewed later.

---

While a fix might be to use `@categories_hash[category_name]` or similar (i.e. fetch/ensure a *different* object each loop), the following avoids the problem described and the unused/misused hash of 'category' keys.

```
categories.each_with_index do |category, index_2|
    # creates a new Hash object
    item = {
        id: "#{index_1}_#{index_2}",
        name: category.text,
        group: group.text
    }
    # adds the new (per yield) object
    @hashes << item
end
```

Alternatively, a more "functional" approach might be to use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), but it solves the problem in the same way - by creating *new* [Hash] objects. (This could be expanded to also include the outer loop, but it's just here for a taste.)

```
h = categories.each_with_index.map do |category, index_2|
    {
        id: "#{index_1}_#{index_2}",
        name: category.text,
        group: group.text
    }
end
@hashes.concat(h)
```